# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Whiles using $_post and Form

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a form to send the chosen value by the user to a query that's inserting it to "assigned_events". The value in the form is generated by PHP with the ID_EVENT and ID_USER numbers. Manually sending the query in PHPMyAdmin into SQL is doing it perfectly fine. Manually setting the values without using $_Post and bindparam does nothing.

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a
> child row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`project_database`.`assigned_events`, CONSTRAINT
> `assigned_events_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_EVENT`) REFERENCES `events`
> (`ID_EVENT`) ON DELETE CASCADE)

**The tables that are used.**

Assigned_events:

```
CREATE TABLE `assigned_events` (
  `ID_ASSIGNED_EVENTS` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `ID_EVENT` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID_USER` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `COMMENT` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Events:

```
CREATE TABLE `events` (
  `ID_EVENT` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `NAME` text NOT NULL,
  `DATE` date NOT NULL,
  `ENDDATE` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Users:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `ID_USER` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `E_MAIL` text NOT NULL,
  `PASSWORD` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `PERMISSIONS` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

Indexes

```
ALTER TABLE `assigned_events`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_ASSIGNED_EVENTS`),
  ADD KEY `ID_EVENT` (`ID_EVENT`),
  ADD KEY `ID_USER` (`ID_USER`);

--
-- Indeksy dla tabeli `events`
--
ALTER TABLE `events`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_EVENT`);

--
-- Indeksy dla tabeli `users`
--
ALTER TABLE `users`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`ID_USER`);
```

And the foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE `assigned_events`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `assigned_events_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_USER`) REFERENCES `users` (`ID_USER`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `assigned_events_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ID_EVENT`) REFERENCES `events` (`ID_EVENT`) ON DELETE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

The query and the code of generating the form options in the main file that's sending it through $_POST:

```
SELECT events.NAME, events.ID_EVENT FROM events;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $id[] = $row['ID_EVENT'];
            $name[] = $row['NAME'];
        }
        for($i=0; $i<count($name) ; $i++){
            echo '<option value="' . $id[$i] .'">' . $name[$i] . '</option>';
        }
```

The code used to send the query to the SQL server taken from the webpage using the $_POST values from the form options.

```
<?php 
    if(!isset($_POST['worker_id'], $_POST['event_id'])){
        header('Location:../index.php');
    } else {
        session_start();
        include_once 'dbconnect.php';
        $worker_id = $_POST['worker_id'];
        $event_id = $_POST['event_id'];
        
        if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `assigned_events` (`ID_EVENT`, `ID_USER`) VALUES (?, ?);')){
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $worker_id, $event_id);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();
        }
        $_SESSION['status'] = 1;
        header('Location: ../edit_event.php');
        $stmt->close();
        mysqli_close($conn);
        exit;
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

TL:DR
I'm using $_post from a PHP form that's generated with the values of ID_USER and ID_EVENT and sent to Insert a relation in table 3 referencing the user and event id from table 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

After today's review of the code the problem here was:

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO `assigned_events` (`ID_EVENT`,`ID_USER`) VALUES (?, ?);')){
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $worker_id, $event_id);
```

The line where the worker_id was showed into ID_EVENT and  event_id into ID_USER...

So the proper code should be:

```
if ($stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `assigned_events` (`ID_EVENT`, `ID_USER`) VALUES (?, ?)")){
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $event_id, $worker_id);
```